# trello api update checkitem state

Tags: api, state, trello

I would like to use the Trello API to update the state of checkItem.

Here is my PUT:

URL: cards/50d3791447d8a71f52000243/checklist/50d3841d65296725520002a0/checkItem/50d384e9c027149d3300074b/state

fields: idCheckList=50d3841d65296725520002a0&idCheckItem=50d384e9c027149d3300074b&value=true

Here is the API reference:

https://trello.com/docs/api/card/index.html#put-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-checklist-idchecklist-checkitem-idcheckitem-state

Every other requests are work correct, but something wrong with this, and I don't know what :(

Comment: What response are you getting?

Answer (score 5):

```
PUT /1/cards/[card id or shortlink]/checklist/[idChecklist]/checkItem/[idCheckItem]/state is the URI.  

https://api.trello.com/1/cards/[card id]/checklist/[checklist id]/checkItem/[checkitem id]/state?key=[your api key]&token=[your trello token]&value=false
```

This would return 200 OK and update the checkitem as incomplete/unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

I had to PUT this url in Postman to update (check) my checklist item :

```
https://api.trello.com/1/cards/123myCard/checkItem/123myItem?state=complete&key=123myKey&token=123myToken
```

[trello developer doc reference](https://developers.trello.com/reference/#cardsidcheckitemidcheckitem-1)